# BeautifulSoup - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, twitter

i'm facing below error I want to get the latest tweet of a specific user, please your help.
BeautifulSoup - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_last_tweet_link(username):
  """
  Gets the link to the last tweet of a user on Twitter.

  Args:
    username: The username of the user on Twitter.

  Returns:
    The link to the last tweet of the user.
  """

  # Get the HTML of the user's Twitter page.
  url = "https://twitter.com/" + username
  response = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

  # Find the last tweet.
  last_tweet = soup.find("div", class_="tweet")

  # Get the link to the last tweet.
  link = last_tweet.find("a", class_="tweet-link").get("href")

  return link

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Get the link to the last tweet of the user "elonmusk".
  link = get_last_tweet_link("elonmusk")

  # Print the link to the last tweet.
  print(link)
```

The code first imports the requests and BeautifulSoup libraries. Then, it defines a function called get_last_tweet_link. This function takes one argument, which is the username of the Twitter user whose last tweet you want to get the link to.

The function first gets the HTML of the user's Twitter page by calling the requests.get function. It then uses the BeautifulSoup library to parse the HTML and create a Python object.

i need someone to help me and fix the code

Comment: `soup.find("div", class_="tweet")` did not find any matching element, so it returned None.

Comment: This might be because you're using `requests`, which cannot process javascript, to fetch the page html.

Comment: @JohnGordon how to fix it

Comment: Use something else, such as selenium, that can process javascript.

Comment: @JohnGordon can you provide me the code please

Comment: See https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html for examples and usage

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error, because `soup.find("div", class_="tweet")` is not found, therefore it returned an error.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge is concerned ,Twitter is no longer returning HTML responses. Instead, they are sending JavaScript code that renders the page. This means that the requests module cannot be used to scrape Twitter data, and that using Selenium may result in being blocked by Twitter. I suggest using the official Twitter API, which is located at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api, but it is not free.